# Taylor Inequality formula confusion. A few questions.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading Stewart's explanation of the Taylor Inequality and I'm a bit lost:

[image]

1. So just to clarify (9)...is it saying that if the $n+1$ derivative of f is $< M$ (M is just some number?) for $x - a \leq d$, then the remainder is $\leq$ some $\frac{M}{(n+1)!} |x-a|^{n+1}$. What is $|x-a| < d$? What is d? What is M? Is d the radius of convergence for x?
2. So this isn't a proof right? This is a demonstration as to why it works for n = 1 right?

Regardless, how do we go from:

$$f'(x) \leq f'(a) + M(x-a)$$

to

$$\int_a^x f'(t) dt \leq \int_a^x [f'(a) + M(t-a)] dt$$ ?

Can you just take the integral of both sides from point a to x and the inequality will hold? Is that a rule?

3. I don't see why $$f(x) - T_1(x) = f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)$$

Is it because $T_1(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$ when n = 1? It's as first degree Taylor series polynomial right?

4. My book says:

> $R_n$ looks a lot like the (n + 1) term of a Taylor series.

Isn't $R_n =$ all the terms after the nth partial sum? 
Why is the book saying it's only the n+1 term?

Comment: $M$ is some *upper bound* on the value of $|f'(x)|$ for $x\in [a-d,a+d]$. For example, suppose $ [a-d,a+d]=[\pi/2,\pi]$ and $f(x) = \sin x$, then $f'(x)=\cos x$ and $|\cos x|\le 1$ for all $x\in [\pi/2,\pi]$. So here, you could take $M=1$ (or any larger value).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this is not really a proof. It is just a demonstration of why things work the way they do.

First of all do not ignore the absolute values in the remainder theorem.

You are correct in asking about the inequality regarding the integral and the location of $ x$ with respect to $a$. $x$ should be on the right side of $a$ for the inequality to hold.

Now for the similarity of the remainder to the next term of the sequence, the remainder theorem indicates that the remainder is indeed in form of

$$ \frac{ f^{(n+1)}(c)(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $$ which is very similar to the next term.

The difference is $c$ is sitting in place of $a$

You may refer to an advanced calculus text for the actual proof of the Taylor remainder theorem and see what is really going on.